# Digitally Controlled Variable Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, integrated-circuit

I'm working on a simple circuit where I have to vary the capacitance across two pins of an IC in the run time. Right now, I use 6 capacitors from **0.001uF to 1uF** and switches between them manually using sticky push buttons. I could use a gang capacitor and vary the value by turning a knob. But I think using some digital controls will be a bit more smarter, such as I replace presets with digital potentiometers like [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10613). Is there any off-the-shelf digitally controlled capacitor ICs? Is there any work-around for this by using some other components?

**Update:** The following is the circuit I'm working with. I need to replace the external timing capacitor **C** with a digitally controlled variable capacitor.
[image]

Comment: www.diystompboxes.com/smfforum/index.php?topic=24307.msg167665#msg167665

Comment: Is one of the pins ground? How much circuit resistance can you tolerate in series with the capacitors?

Comment: @Andyaka No, none of the pins are ground. [This](https://github.com/subinsebastien/rowfiles/raw/master/21.8.13/xr2206-circuit.png) is the circuit I'm working with. I need to replace the external timing capacitor **C** with a digitally controlled variable capacitor.

Comment: Honestly, I would use a different solution for making a function generator.  I don't know exactly what, because that would depend on what you are using it for.  But switching caps in/out can be problematic and just seems like the wrong approach.  Every time I have an issue like this I can always come up with a cleaner solution by taking a step back and re-evaluating the whole approach to the problem.

Comment: @DavidKessner Agreed. This is just a hobby circuit. But the sole question is not specifically about this circuit. Just as like we have digital potentiometers, we don't seems to have digitally controlled capacitors. My question was to find answer to that problem.

Comment: @SubinSebastian  Don't get me wrong: there is absolutely nothing wrong with trying!  As I often say at my office, "we need to do this if only so we can say, with confidence, why we shouldn't do this".  By the way, it is possible to apply a DC bias to some DIODES and vary their capacitance.  This is how Voltage Controlled Crystal Oscillators are done. But their tuning range is small and in the low-pF range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a FET bus switch, like the [SN74CBT3125](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74cbt3125.pdf), however this will add about 5 ohms resistance in series with each capacitor.  If that is a problem, you could always use reed relays like [this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/9007-05-00/306-1062-ND/301696), each driven by a FET or BJT transistor, which would exactly emulate your current arrangement with the pushbuttons.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be a bit different approach. Which one of these will provide faster switching?

Comment: @SubinSebastian The FET switch would operate in a few ns.  The relay would switch in about a ms.

Answer (score 1):

Check it, this may solve your problem [Psemi](http://www.psemi.com/pdf/sell_sheet-psg/73-0039.pdf)
Or sometimes [varactor diodes](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MMBV105GLT1-D.PDF) can also be used, but they require, bigger circuitry and controlling method to control the capacitance.
[Link](http://electronics-diy.com/varicaps.php) shows the use of varactor diodes to design variable capacitors using 10K pot. Here instead of using a 10K manual pot, a digitally controlled resistor can be used, whose resistance can be controlled using I2C or SPI. But this particular approach requires experiments.

Comment: Varactors and tuneable capacitor systems are orders of magnitude smaller than the values of capacitance required by OQ.

Comment: @JImDearden so use a varactor as the input source to the capacitance "multiplier" circuit linked in Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams comment. :-)  Sounds like a fun project.

Comment: @akohlsmith and multiplying up the value also multiplies up the drifts :-( but I did like the gyrator circuit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better of going totally digital. Just change everything to a [DDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_digital_synthesizer).

Here is one [example project](http://www.frankvh.com/dds-signal-generator.html).